# CSS center positioning on all resolutions

Tags: html, css

Hi im trying to position my website in the centre of all resolutions however when i wrap the entire page in a container div and try styling it nothing happens , below is the CSS i use :

CSS

```
             .container {
width: 95%;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
}
```

Any suggestion on how i can fix?

Comment: You aren't showing enough for us to help. Need a link or a jsfiddle so we can see your html, too. Your width is 95%. 95% of what? What is its parent set to? If it's the body, I presume, then have you set it to anything?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Lezuus/Q2NvB/

Answer (score 0):

Your container div IS centered but you've set margins on the left side for the nav element of 220px. I have not looked at the others yet but I presume you have left margins set on those, too.

Also, your elements inside the container are positioned absolutely which will take them out of the normal flow. If you want those elements to be attached to .container then you need to make it position:relative.

Something I mentioned in my previous comment above, you have to remember that when you set a width to a percent to ask yourself, "Percent of what?". It will always be a percent of the width of the parent so the next question is, "What is the width of the parent?". If that's not set then your percentage may not work the way you intend it to, or at all.